# Nebular - after login not getting token payload properly

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt, nebular

I am using `nebular` and `laravel` API with `NbPasswordAuthStrategy` and `NbAuthJWTToken` class, as follwoing:

```
NbAuthModule.forRoot({
  strategies: [
    NbPasswordAuthStrategy.setup({
      name: 'email',
      token: {
        class: NbAuthJWTToken,
        key: 'data.user.token',
      },
      baseEndpoint: BASE_URL + 'users/',
      login: {
        endpoint: 'login',
        method: 'post',
        redirect: {
          success: '/pages/dashboard',
          failure: null, // stay on the same page
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  forms: {
    login: {
      rememberMe: false,
    },
    validation: {
      password: {
        minLength: 6,
      },
    },
  },
}),
```

the `login` endpoint response as following:

```
{
"data": {
    "user": {
        "id": 114683,
        "first_name": "mhd",
        "last_name": "sultan",
        ...
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjgwMDAvYXBpL3VzZXJzL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTcyMzQ2NDMzLCJleHAiOjE2NjY5NTQ0MzMsIm5iZiI6MTU3MjM0NjQzMywianRpIjoiNmxGaDNwbWd0RVpoa0FPRSIsInN1YiI6MTE0NjgzLCJwcnYiOiI4N2UwYWYxZWY5ZmQxNTgxMmZkZWM5NzE1M2ExNGUwYjA0NzU0NmFhIn0.Eg4_1cXngafs1V80jqygvJDR0vZN5HuHyXV9PTeUkzA",
    }
}}
```

in my `UserService` when I **subscribe** to *onTokenChange*:

```
constructor(private authService: NbAuthService) {
this.authService.onTokenChange()
  .subscribe((token: NbAuthJWTToken) => {
    console.log(token);
    console.log(token.getPayload());
    if (token.isValid()) {
      this.user = token.getPayload(); // receive payload from token and assign it to our `user` variable
    }
  });}
```

I am getting the token **properly**  but I am getting a payload that contains JWT token properties

[image]

what should I do to get the `data.user` object ??

Answer (score 1):

All the data you want to get back from payload should be encoded at the time you create your jwt token :

```
jwt.sign({
payload,
SECRET,
expiration,
});
```

and then the data is available with `token.getPayload()`